# I cant go beyond npm start in react and I cannot find stackoveflow solution that fits

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So Im trying to learn react and I could usually find quick solutions in stackoverflow but the thing is, I've many solutions suggested here like clearing the cache or changing my webpack version but I still could not fix the error and Im stumped.

C:\Users\garci\Desktop\reactApp\myfirstreact>npm start

> myfirstreact@0.1.0 start C:\Users\garci\Desktop\reactApp\myfirstreact
> react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"webpack": "4.44.2"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

C:\Users\garci\node_modules\webpack (version: 1.15.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Users\garci\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
   This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myfirstreact@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myfirstreact@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\garci\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-22T16_21_07_888Z-debug.log

C:\Users\garci\Desktop\reactApp\myfirstreact>

and yes I tried to follow the steps given by the cli but it still give the same error. here is my debug log too.

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [

1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'start'

1 verbose cli ]

2 info using npm@6.14.13

3 info using node@v14.17.3

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~prestart: myfirstreact@0.1.0

6 info lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~start: myfirstreact@0.1.0

7 verbose lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-
bin;C:\Users\garci\Desktop\reactApp\myfirstreact\node_modules.bin;C:\Python39\Scripts;C:\Python3

9;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R)
Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engin
Components\iCLS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Windo
wsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program

Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R)
Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common

Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL

Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program

Files\nodejs;C:\Users\garci\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\garci\AppData\Roaming\np
m

9 verbose lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\garci\Desktop\reactApp\myfirstreact

10 silly lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]

11 silly lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle myfirstreact@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script

13 verbose stack Error: myfirstreact@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)

13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)

14 verbose pkgid myfirstreact@0.1.0

15 verbose cwd C:\Users\garci\Desktop\reactApp\myfirstreact

16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042

17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

18 verbose node v14.17.3

19 verbose npm  v6.14.13

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error myfirstreact@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the myfirstreact@0.1.0 start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I realize it might be that I just need to install another version of webpack but it says I should not do it manually and even if I would, I do not know how. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have webpack installed globally, which could be conflicting with CRA. It's not recommended to have it installed globally anyway. Run `npm list -g` to see global packages, and run `npm uninstall -g webpack` if it is listed, then check again to see if it's gone. If that doesn't work for your existing directory create a fresh CRA app just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an `.env` file at the root of your app and add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` in it. Then restart your app. It should work.